# Variables in Vim Plugin

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I write a vim plugin to learn some vimscript.
I set the variables in the `/autoload/plugin.vim` like this:

```
let g:configpath = '~/home/username/.vim/bundle/testplugin/templates/'
let g:config = '/config.h'
```

Then I want to use it within a function:

```
function! testplugin#template(...)
    :e g:configpath  . a:1 . g:config   
endfunction
```

The goal is to open the file behind this path. *a:1* is a user-given input because the subfolder is selectable by the user.

When I use `echo g:configpath  . a:1 . g:config` the correct path will be print out to Vim but when I use `:e` to open the file Vim open a new file with the name:

```
"g:configpath . a:1 . g:config" [New]
```

How do I open the template file behind this path?

Comment: Are you trying to write a *plugin* or an *autoload script*? See `:help write-plugin` and `:help autoload` for the differences. It looks like you're trying to do something in between which may be the reason things don't work as expected.

Comment: oh. I thought with plugins /autoload controls the functions and /plugin the userinput and commands to be used in vim. is this not necessary?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do. The plugin-thing threw me off. You're trying to do `:e g:foo` and want the variable to expand, right? Is that the essence of your problem? In that case, see `:help execute`.

Comment: There you go. While I was busy writing comments romainl wrote an answer you can print out and put in a gold frame :-)

Comment: Haha, meetings…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:help :echo` and `:help :edit_f` handle arguments differently.

The former expects an expression, which is evaluated at runtime to produce the text that will be echoed:

```
:let $FOO = 'foo'
:let g:bar = 'bar'
:echo $FOO .. g:bar .. 'baz' .. eval('1+2')
foobarbaz3
```

The latter also does *some* evaluation but it is limited to expanding environment variables and the items documented under `:help cmdline-special`. Most notably it can't do concatenation:

```
:let $DIR = '/path/to/dir'
:edit $DIR/filename
:edit %<.stories.ts
```

If you want to build the filename programmatically, you have two options.

- Use `:help :execute`:

  ```
  :let filename = '/path/to/filename'
  :execute 'edit ' .. filename
  :execute 'edit ' .. <some expression that evaluates to a filename>
  ```
- Use an environment variable:

  ```
  :let $FILENAME = '/path/to/filename'
  :edit $FILENAME
  ```

FWIW, autoloaded scripts don't seem to be the right place for defining global options. They are usually defined in `plugin/foo.vim`.

Comment: well. I will print it out and goldframe it. This works perfectly. Thanks for this